# How to get return data from PHP file via AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a contact form with PHP and AJAX. The email sends and all but it always says `"Failed to send!"` even in the console it says `"true"` which should result in the html `"Message Sent!"`

So I wrote this in the end of my PHP script:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "true";    
}
```

and that should mean that via AJAX the output data I get should be one of those, correct?

```
                ajax.SetText("Sending...");
                $.post("sendmail.php", {
                    name: userName, email: userEmail, comments: userComments, business: currentBusiness, website: currentWebsite
                }, function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {

                        ajax.SetText("Sent!");  
                        console.log(data);


                        $.get("sent.html", function(sentData){

                            $("#content").html(sentData);

                        });

                    } else {
                        ajax.SetText("Send mail");
                        console.log(data);
                        $.get("unsent.html", function(sentData){

                            $("#content").html(sentData);

                        });


                    }

                    ajax.isSubmiting = false;
                });
```

This is the jQuery^

So basically if the email is sent I want the return to be "true" so then I could put the appropiate information on the page like "The message was sent!" But in this case, whether it fails to send or succeeds, it never returns true. I have also tried, in the php file, `print_r("true")` and `die("true")` but it still doesnt work. Does anyone know why? Any thing would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the system is taking `"true"` to be a keyword. Try putting `OK` or something. Also check if you aren't outputting an extra line. You can do this by checking with `.trim()`.

```
if (data.trim() == "true") {
```

To check such kind of issues, try on the console using `encodeURI()` function:

```
console.log(encodeURI(data));
```

This might give you something similar to:

[image: console]

I created an <kbd>Enter</kbd> line on the output. This might not match if you check with:

```
data == "true"
```

So you might need to use the `trim()` function here. Look at the below for more information:

[image: console]

I strongly believe this would be the case. `:)`

Comment: I thought that would work too but same thing happens. And in the console it says true so i'm very lost

Comment: Console says true? Did you do the `console.log(encodeURI(data));`? What's the output of this?

Comment: I found the problem! So in the script (im using PHPMailer) I had this line of code "$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;" and as soon as I removed it it worked flawlessly. Thanks!